# Moody's seasoned corporate bond yields

Tags: yield-curve, yield, rates

The Fed publishes Moody's seasoned corporate bond yields [here](http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/data.htm).

These yields are not broken out by maturity.

According to [this](https://www.economy.com/support/blog/buffet.aspx?did=06CB74FA-CBB9-4732-BC63-AE9B63AF8DF6) website, the yields represent "long-term" bonds, with minimum and average maturities of 20 and 28 years, respectively. First of all, can anyone validate this?

Second - are there short/medium term 'Moody's seasoned corporate bond yields' published for free anywhere.

If not - where can I find a free data source for short term, medium and long term corporate bond yields?

I want to compare corporate bond yields against the treasury yield curve to assess credit spreads. Unfortunately, if the above is true, I only have data for the long end.

Thanks,